# Jquery attr Open New Window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to open a URL in Jquery which works fine however I would like the window to open in a target _new way.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(location).attr('href', 'http://www.google.com');
</script>
```

I have tried adding

```
.attr('target','new');
```

and some variations but to no joy. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `$(location).attr("target","_blank");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want open url in new page you can use:

```
window.open("http://stackoverflow.com/", '_blank');
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/mxfqo12o/